# MultiAxisChart In Jasper report both axis are coming left side

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I was able to start with MultiAxis Chart with Jasper report using Link : [create MultiAxis Chart with Jasper report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oXaT.png).

I was able to creat the chart as well but not completely formatted. I was having Axis Problem. Both X-axis are coming on left side. How do I move one Axis of bar chart on right side. Following is the picture of my current problem:

[image]

Following is my jrxml content.

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="cutting_indicator_cutter" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
                <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
                <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
                <property name="ireport.y" value="48"/>
                <subDataset name="chart1">
                    <queryString language="SQL">
                        <![CDATA[select Q.proddate,NVL(Q.m2NetReel,0)
            ,case when Q.HMO <> 0 then
                                                      NVL((Q.m2NetReel/Q.HMO),0)
                                                  end  as m2NETBYHMO,
                                                  Q.Objectif_HMOBY1000
            from (

            SELECT
              PROD_DATE as proddate,
              case when CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.REMAKE_CUT_SQM  is null then CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.CUTTER_NET_SQM
              else
                   CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.CUTTER_NET_SQM +  CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.REMAKE_CUT_SQM
              end as m2NetReel,
               (CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.MACHINE_WORKING_HOURS_NORM * CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.USER_QUANTITY ) as HMO,
               1000/(CUTTING_MACHINE.CADENCY*19.26) as Objectif_HMOBY1000


            FROM  CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY
            INNER JOIN  CUTTING_MACHINE CUTTING_MACHINE
            ON CUTTING_MACHINE_ID=CUTTING_MACHINE.CUTTING_ID where trunc(CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.PROD_DATE) >= '1-May-15' and trunc( CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.PROD_DATE ) <='31-May-15'
            ORDER BY CUTTER) Q]]>
                    </queryString>
                    <field name="PRODDATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
                    <field name="NVL(Q.M2NETREEL,0)" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                    <field name="M2NETBYHMO" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                    <field name="OBJECTIF_HMOBY1000" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                </subDataset>
                <queryString>
                    <![CDATA[SELECT EST_CUTTER_GLASSES_QTY,
              CUTTER_NET_SQM,
              REMAKE_CUT_QTY,
              PROD_DATE,
              REMAKE_CUT_SQM,
              CUTTING_MACHINE.CADENCY,
              USER_QUANTITY,
              CUTTER,
              MACHINE_WORKING_HOURS_NORM
            FROM  CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY
            INNER JOIN  CUTTING_MACHINE CUTTING_MACHINE
            ON CUTTING_MACHINE_ID=CUTTING_MACHINE.CUTTING_ID
            where trunc(CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.PROD_DATE) >= '1-May-15' and trunc( CUTTING_PRODUCTIVITY.PROD_DATE ) <='31-May-15'
            ORDER BY CUTTER]]>
                </queryString>
                <field name="EST_CUTTER_GLASSES_QTY" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                <field name="CUTTER_NET_SQM" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                <field name="REMAKE_CUT_QTY" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                <field name="PROD_DATE" class="java.sql.Timestamp"/>
                <field name="REMAKE_CUT_SQM" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                <field name="CADENCY" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                <field name="USER_QUANTITY" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                <field name="CUTTER" class="java.lang.String"/>
                <field name="MACHINE_WORKING_HOURS_NORM" class="java.math.BigDecimal"/>
                <group name="CUTTER">
                    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{CUTTER}]]></groupExpression>
                    <groupHeader>
                        <band height="325">
                            <frame>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="325" printWhenGroupChanges="CUTTER"/>
                                <multiAxisChart>
                                    <chart renderType="svg" theme="generic">
                                        <reportElement x="24" y="0" width="486" height="325">
                                            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.chart.range.axis.tick.interval" value="2"/>
                                        </reportElement>
                                        <chartTitle/>
                                        <chartSubtitle/>
                                        <chartLegend position="Bottom"/>
                                    </chart>
                                    <multiAxisPlot>
                                        <plot/>
                                        <axis>
                                            <lineChart>
                                                <chart renderType="svg">
                                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    <chartTitle color="#000000"/>
                                                    <chartSubtitle color="#000000"/>
                                                    <chartLegend textColor="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" position="Bottom"/>
                                                </chart>
                                                <categoryDataset>
                                                    <dataset>
                                                        <datasetRun subDataset="chart1">
                                                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                                                        </datasetRun>
                                                    </dataset>
                                                    <categorySeries>
                                                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["WEIGHTAVG"]]></seriesExpression>
                                                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODDATE}]]></categoryExpression>
                                                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{NVL(Q.M2NETREEL,0)}]]></valueExpression>
                                                    </categorySeries>
                                                    <categorySeries>
                                                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["OBJECTIF"]]></seriesExpression>
                                                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODDATE}]]></categoryExpression>
                                                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{OBJECTIF_HMOBY1000}]]></valueExpression>
                                                    </categorySeries>
                                                </categoryDataset>
                                                <linePlot isShowLines="true" isShowShapes="true">
                                                    <plot labelRotation="-45.0"/>
                                                </linePlot>
                                            </lineChart>
                                        </axis>
                                        <axis>
                                            <barChart>
                                                <chart renderType="svg">
                                                    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="0" height="0" backcolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                                                    <chartTitle color="#000000"/>
                                                    <chartSubtitle color="#000000"/>
                                                    <chartLegend textColor="#000000" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" position="Bottom"/>
                                                </chart>
                                                <categoryDataset>
                                                    <dataset>
                                                        <datasetRun subDataset="chart1">
                                                            <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                                                        </datasetRun>
                                                    </dataset>
                                                    <categorySeries>
                                                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["M2NetHMO"]]></seriesExpression>
                                                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{PRODDATE}]]></categoryExpression>
                                                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{M2NETBYHMO}]]></valueExpression>
                                                    </categorySeries>
                                                </categoryDataset>
                                                <barPlot>
                                                    <plot/>
                                                    <itemLabel/>
                                                </barPlot>
                                            </barChart>
                                        </axis>
                                    </multiAxisPlot>
                                </multiAxisChart>
                            </frame>
                        </band>
                    </groupHeader>
                </group>
                <background>
                    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
                </background>
                <title>
                    <band height="50"/>
                </title>
            </jasperReport>
```

How do I move my bar chart axis to right?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi sorry I am able to add verticle bars not able to add line with horizontal  withj square boxes.
I am using ireport 4.5.1 .

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your current approach; the `OverlaidBarChartDemo[12]` and `DualAxisDemo1` classes are examples.

Comment: I was not able to format the X-axis of this chart. I have posted complete example. Please let me know what other stuff you require ?

Comment: I don't use [tag:jasper-reports]; `CategoryPlot#setRangeAxisLocation()` is the relevant [tag:jfreechart] method. Can you fix the link to the original article?

Answer (score 0):

To move an axis to the right side of the chart in jasper reports, you'll need to create a Customizer for your chart. Once you do that, the following commands in your customizer will move your axis to the right side of the chart:

```
// get plot from chart object
CategoryPlot plot = (CategoryPlot) chart.getPlot();

// move axis to right side of chart
plot.setRangeAxisLocation(AxisLocation.BOTTOM_OR_RIGHT);
```